# Use PowerShell to quickly test whether the content of two files is identical

Tags: powershell

As part of a larger PowerShell script, I want to test whether the contents of two binary files are identical.

I think the following is logically correct:

```
if (@(Compare-Object 
    $(Get-Content f1.txt -encoding byte) 
    $(Get-Content f2.txt -encoding byte) 
    -sync 0).length -eq 0) {
    "same" 
} else {
    "different"
}
```

However, the above runs very slowly as it's really using Compare-Object for something that is begging for a much simpler implementation.

I'm looking for something that gives the same logical result, but uses some faster low level file comparison.

I do not need or want any description of the differences, or any text output, just a logical test that gives me a boolean result.

Comment: The Get-Content cmdlet runs faster with large files using the parameter -ReadCount 0

Answer (score 5):

If the files are large, causing compare-object to take much time, you can generate SHA1 hash and compare it.

Or you can read the files byte-by-byte in a loop, breaking at the first non-equal bytes.

Comment: You can use [FCIV.EXE](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841290/en-us) to compute hash.

Comment: I would recommend a calculation of a hash-value too. PSCX-Module has a hash-cmdlet.

Comment: @Tom Yeah, we can use the PSCX cmdlet or .Net libraries or external exe for that, no dearth of tools...

Comment: Hash value would be your first step. If they are the same, then you need to binary compare them to be certain. Try `cmd /c fc /?` ... and check the exit codes.

Comment: With the Get-FileHash cmdlets I agree the hash solution is simple. However since a byte by byte comparison is bound to be faster, it’s a shame there isn’t a succinct way to code it. It seems that it would have to be C# loop with a break on the first difference to get reasonable performance.

Answer (score 4):

```
if ($(Get-FileHash $fileA).Hash -ne $(Get-FileHash $fileB).Hash) {
  Write-Output "Files $fileA and $fileB aren't equal"
}
```